# .Net KeyEventArgs return vs enter

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

Have this in a c# .net application:

string key = e.KeyCode.ToString();

in .net 1.1 key = "enter"

in .net 3.5 key = "return"

my question is why are they different?

Comment: Do both applications have the same CultureInfo?

Comment: Yes - the exact same application only one is compiled with vs2003 .net 1.1 and the other with vs2008 .net 3.5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Keys` enum has identical values for `Enter` and `Return`  (it also has a number of other duplicates).  The framework chose a different value in `ToString`.

Comment: thats it, verified here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(VS.71).aspx

if anyone has a cheat sheet that would be awesome.

Comment: showing what values are the same such as the enter and return key in the keys enum.  you mentioned there are other duplicates.

Comment: Run this code:  `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).GroupBy(k => Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k)).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)`

Comment: It's actually a shame since having different enter and return can be useful

Comment: I think he means different main area enter and numpad enter

Answer (score 10):

Here are all of the duplicate names:
This was generated by the following query in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.com):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys))
    .GroupBy(k => Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => String.Join(", ", g.Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray()))
```

---

```
Enter, Return
CapsLock, Capital
HangulMode, HanguelMode, KanaMode
KanjiMode, HanjaMode
IMEAccept, IMEAceept
Prior, PageUp
PageDown, Next
Snapshot, PrintScreen
OemSemicolon, Oem1
Oem2, OemQuestion
Oem3, Oemtilde
Oem4, OemOpenBrackets
OemPipe, Oem5
OemCloseBrackets, Oem6
OemQuotes, Oem7
Oem102, OemBackslash
```